# Extracting a row in python from an alphanumerical array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array in python, I want to extract rows which end in p into a new array.

```
array([[ 0,   6,   p],
       [ 1,   7,   m],
       [ 2,  10,   m],
       [ 3,   4,   p],
       [ 4,   1,   m],
       [ 5,  10,   p],
       [ 6,   6,   m],
       [ 7,   4,   m],
       [ 8,   6,   p],
       [ 9,   7,   p]])
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code this yourself? If so, can you please share?

Comment: is `p` really `"p"` ?

Comment: Is `p` an integer variable you've defined somewhere?

Comment: p is a letter as shown in the array.  The array was created using the list function and the p and m characters were present in the array.  I have converted the arrays with array1 = np.asarray(listreadversion)

Answer (score 2):

the easy way is to use a numpy boolean index as below

```
a = numpy.array(a) # ensure its a numpy array
print a[a[:,-1]=="p"]
```

to break it down

```
mask = a[:,-1]=="p" #gives an array of True/False that is the same as the array, based on if last char is "p"
a[mask]  #indexes into the original array returning only the rows that end with "p"
```

Comment: The original array is read with the list function, and when I try this I get TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: why did you tag it numpy if its not a numpy array? ... anyway edited to make it a numpy array ...

Comment: I got it to work with newarray= a[np.where(a[:,-1] =="p") ].  This was after converting it to a numpy array array1 = np.asarray(listreadversion).

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to solve this.

```
data = [
    [ 0,   6,   "p"],
    [ 1,   7,   "m"],
    [ 2,  10,   "m"],
    [ 3,   4,   "p"],
    [ 4,   1,   "m"],
    [ 5,  10,   "p"],
    [ 6,   6,   "m"],
    [ 7,   4,   "m"],
    [ 8,   6,   "p"],
    [ 9,   7,   "p"]
]

new_data = filter(lambda l: l[2] == "p", data)
```

The above structure assumes you are dealing with a list of lists (array of arrays), however the same should apply to tuples and dictionaries.

Here is a reference to the filter function:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: We are not dealing with lists, tuples, or dictionaries. We are dealing with a NumPy array. `filter` will be slow and return a list; we want a NumPy solution.

Comment: So he is. That makes this answer more reasonable (though I'd go for a list comprehension rather than `filter`). My vote's locked, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

this is quite easily in python.

you can just do:

```
p = array[SOME_RANDOM_CELL];
print p[0]
```

Comment: As this is a NumPy question, we're looking for a way to extract all rows with `p` as the last element in a loop-free manner. Indexing to retrieve individual elements is easy.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake. im new to this site and am not in the habit of looking at tags